# What is the correct grep regex-string for searching any words after a left-parenthesis starting with a specific letter?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

In some of my python-scripts, I got `glob.glob(parent_folder_path + glob_str)`.
These lines with the associated files shall be printed out in the console with a proper grep command, but so far I couldn't find out how.

The one which worked for finding all the `glob.glob` - lines is the following:

```
grep --exclude-dir='.history' --exclude-dir='__pycache__' --exclude-dir='.wine' -Rinw /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -e 'glob.glob'
```

Still it's not the preciseness I would like to achieve.
When using `'glob.glob(p*'` as the regex-string, only a line with `glob.glob()` appears in the search result. I couldn't make sense out of this since `(p*` gave me results with `()`.

Next, I tried `'glob.glob(p.*'` which indeed worked out and showed me all results with `glob.glob(parent_folder_path + glob_str)`.

Even though I managed to find it out via trial and error, I'd like to understand the grep-syntax better.
Did the last regex-string work because, according to [this cheat-sheet](https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/cheatsheetgrep.php), `.` stands for any character and `*` for any number of repeated times?

Comment: `p*.` means zero-or-more occurrences of `p` character followed by a single character; what pattern do you want to match? answer based on title of the question you only need `(p\w+`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I actually had `'glob.glob(p.*'` working, that's what I wanted to state here, but wrote initially `'glob.glob(p*.'`. Thanks for the hint. Your suggestion of `(p\w+` did not work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close in your guess.  In a regular expression, the sequence `p*.` means "zero or more of the character `p`, followed by exactly one of any character":

- `*` - Zero or more of the preceding token
- `.` - Exactly one character

The more common "global wildcard" in regular expression is `.*` which means "One or more of any type of character".

Your guess worked because you did not have a `$` token (indicating "end of domain") in your expression.

In this case you would probably want the expression `/glob\.glob(p.*/`:

- `glob\.glob(p` - the literal string `glob.glob(p`, followed by
- `.*` - at least one of any type of character

To expound further, if for example you wanted to match more broadly all calls to `glob.glob()`, you could do something like `/glob\.glob\([a-z_+ ]+\)/`:

- `glob\.glob\(` - the literal string `glob.glob(`
- `[a-z_+ ]+` - one or more of any of: any letter a-z, an underscore, a `+`, or a space
- `\)` - a literal `)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I've fully understood why my final approach worked. Nevertheless, I tried out your most elaborate suggestion without a single result returned. Is this due the fact that `grep -e` doesn't understand certain regex-syntax? The one I tried based in your final suggestion was: `grep --exclude-dir='.history' --exclude-dir='__pycache__' --exclude-dir='.wine' -Rinw /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -e '/glob\.glob\([a-z_+ ]+\)/'` --> no result returned

Comment: Apologies for being unclear- the leading and trailing slashes are a common identifier for "this is a regular expression" (comparable to how quotation marks are a common identifier for "this is an exact quotation") - the actual expression itself does not include them.

Comment: Okay, now I've removed the quotation marks '..' around your suggested regex, so `grep -Rinw /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -e /glob\.glob\([a-z_+ ]+\)/` results in an error `grep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=`. I don't know how to employ your suggested regex correctly.

Comment: When I simply run `grep -E  'glob\.glob\([a-z_+ ]+\)' foo.py` on an test file, it works perfectly.  In your case, try replacing the `-e` with `-Ee` to use an Extended Regular Expression, which I believe we need because of the `+` token.

Comment: Finally, that was it: we need both e-flags `Ee` to make it work, put the regex into quotes and remove the leading and trailing slashes. The working result is: `grep /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -Ee 'glob\.glob\([a-z_+ ]+\)'`